# Femminile di ei, forma contratta di egli

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Stavo cercando di mettere al femminile la seguente frase da *Le nozze di Figaro* di Mozart.

> *Egli fa tutto ben quello ch’ei fa*

Però mi è sorto un dubbio per il quale non sono riuscito a trovare risposta:

qual è il femminile della forma contratta ***ei***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Risponde lo stesso libretto de *Le Nozze di Figaro*:

> E perch'**ella**? ostinata ognor rifiuta (atto secondo, scena prima)
>
> E Susanna? chi sa ch'**ella** tradito (atto terzo, scena seconda)
>
> Ch'**ella** non fosse... ah quando il cor non ci arma (atto quarto, scena quarta)

Answer (score 2):

Come è detto nella risposta di Giuseppe Romanazzi, il femminile è il pronome *ella*. Lo puoi anche trovare sulla [voce "egli" nel *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000073.jpg), in cui si afferma che *egli*

> ha  come  varianti: *ei*  e  il  suo tronca­mento *e'*, letter. e ant.

Un po' più avanti in questa stessa voce trovi la risposta alla tua domanda:

> il femm. corrispondente è *ella*

Comment: La domanda chiedeva quale fosse la forma contratta, che sembra non esistere.